# Get one timepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I need to display in a View a DateTime like this timepicker(like the first one and without the am or pm time): http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

I don´t want to use bootstrap because I will need to fix all my css, and when I put it inside my project the older css was not working well because the new one had some particular id or html tags in common. I can use Jquery but I don´t know any plugin that do the same thing, remember, I don´t want to display the calendar, just the interval of time, for example 1h:02m
or 1:02, just that

Comment: A google search for "jquery timepicker" returns many results. Have you looked at others? Ultimately, you may end up designing your own modal popup to make it work and look for your needs.

Comment: what does `display duration of time` mean? Provide sample output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl  I edited again the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://github.com/perifer/timePicker/blob/master/index.htm

 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.timePicker.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ()
        {
            // Default.
            $("#time1").timePicker(
                {
                    startTime: "00.00",
                    endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 6, 30, 0),
                    show24Hours: true,
                    separator: ':',
                    step: 3
                }
            );
        })
    </script>

@section styles{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/timePicker.css")
}
```

Comment: I know you're answering your own question so you understand why this helps. But it would be much more helpful to others if you explained how this code solves your problem.

Comment: I just needed a control to display a timepicker like the bootstrap ui has. This sample includes the timepicker.js and css(inside the section style). Start time is to display the first option of time to select, the hour 00:00 and end time was 06:30, show24hours option hides from the control am and pm format, step: 3 means that the control will have all the hours in with the previous format with .3 minutes of difference. The sequence is like this: 00:00 00:03 00:06.... 06:27 06:30

Answer (score 0):

Personally for date/time requirements I prefer [KendoUI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/timepicker/index.html) Timepicker!
The only problem I faced was that I couldn't get to use the standalone timepicker.js, I had to use whole kendoweb.js. It has good documentation with many preinstalled themes.